# Label is not aligning to left

Tags: sapui5, text-alignment

I am trying to align a label to the left and I have given the property for it in the XML view and also in CSS file but it doesn't change at all

[image]

XML

```
<Label text="Buyer Name" textAlign="Left" class="customFontSimpleForm"  />
```

CSS

```
.sapMLabel {
    float: left;
    text-align : left;
}
```

Comment: just asking ..Shouldn't the class name in css be customFontSimpleForm ?

Comment: Are you using the `SimpleForm` control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `SimpleForm` control then you can use the below CSS

```
.sapUiForm .sapUiFormElementLbl>.sapMLabel {
    text-align: left !important;
    width : auto;
}
```

Note: Update the selectors as per your requirement